# difference between prepare and preparing

Tags: complementation, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which sentence is correct and why?

It will help me to prepare for the exam.

It will help me preparing for the exam.

Answer (score 1):

You first sentence

> 1) It will help me **to prepare** for the exam.

is correct **grammatically**

In your second sentence

> 2) It will help me **preparing** for the exam.

is **incorrect**.

**Preparing** is used as a **gerund** and you would need to add

> 3) It will help me **in** preparing for the exam.
>   4) It will help me **while** preparing for the exam.

or

> 5) It will help me **prepare** for the exam.

Comment: So, if my exam is next week I should use first sentence, right ? I don't exactly understand your explanation about second one.

Comment: "Future tense" is not relevant to the question: the answer would have been identical if it had been in another tense, eg "It always helps me to prepare/*preparing for the exam".

Comment: @Yeynno For your exam next week, you can use any of the sentences except \#2 which is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct:

> It will help me to prepare for the exam.

The verb **help** takes either a to-infinitive (**to prepare**) or a bare infinitive (**prepare**):

> It will help me prepare for the exam.

As Peter said, **preparing** is a gerund: this word works like a noun. The verb **help** doesn't take nouns directly, so we need to use some preposition:

> Please help me **with** my homework.
>   This will help me **with** my homework.
>   This will help me **in** making my homework.
>   This will help me **in** preparing for the exam.

There are verbs that take nouns and gerunds directly:

> I will **try** preparing for the exam.
>   I will **try** this apple pie.

See? The difference between "(to) prepare" and "preparing" is that the first is a verb and the second is an **ing** form that works like a gerund (almost like a noun) or a present participle. The verb **help** does not take the **ing** forms directly (without some preposition like **in**, **with**, etc.) That's why your second sentence looks strange, although the meaning of it is easy to understand.